# Personal sites are not getting created after feature stapling

Tags: branding, mysite

I used this[blog](http://sharepointologic.blogspot.in/2013/04/branding-sharepoint-2013-my-sites-with.html) for My Site feature stapling. After installing this, personal sites are getting created and automatically gets deleted within few minutes.

If I change template name to `SPSPERS#0` it works fine, but branding doesn't get applied automatically. I have to run PowerShell for each new personal site created.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: are you using 2013?

Comment: YES>>sharepoint 2013

Comment: When you say the personal site is getting created and then deleted, when it is in fact created, does the branding feature get automatically activated?

Comment: hello eric. i resolved issue by creating new project from scratch.i was using wrong feature id in event receiver which caused the problem.